# Get Facebook friend list on Login using Ionic & Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I want to save an array of user's Facebook friends using Ionic.
I able to save the name and photo and am wondering how to get friend list.
I would love to get the Friends User UIDs as well. I'm using Firebase Authentication.

```
facebookLogin(): Promise<any> {
return this.facebook.login(['email'])
  .then( (response) => {
    const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
      .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);

    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
    .then( userData => { this.userProfileRef.child(userData.uid).set({
    hypes: 23,
    name: userData.displayName,
    image: userData.photoURL,
    friends: userData.friends,
  }); this.userUID = userData.uid;
     })
    .catch((error) => { console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error)); });

  })
  .catch((error) => { console.log(error) }); }}
```

Comment: what for do you need the friends exactly? you can only get friends who authorized your app too.

Comment: I only want the friends who also have downloaded the app. The data I want from each friend is their Name, PhotoURL and Firebase UID. The end goal of my app is to allow 1 user to send coins to their friends. Thank you for commenting on my question.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get the friends list from Firebase. You will need to use the Facebook API. Since you already have the Facebook access token, you can just query the Facebook API for it. You can follow this guide for how to get that with the HTTP request: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/
You will need to make sure you request the necessary scope for that "user_friends".